# MacOSX screensaver not loading due to Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAppKit.dylib

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, screensaver

We have a working Mac OS X screensaver as a standalone Xcode project, but we needed to have it as a target in another Xcode project that also contains a related app.

I added a target for a screensaver, copied the code, added to that target, etc, etc. The code is the same one that works in the other screensaver, but on this one, it generates the following error:

```
2015-03-10 09:43:24.766 System Preferences[32495]: Error loading /Users/pupeno/Library/Screen Savers/Ninja.saver/Contents/MacOS/Ninja:  dlopen(/Users/pupeno/Library/Screen Savers/Ninja.saver/Contents/MacOS/Ninja, 265): Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAppKit.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/pupeno/Library/Screen Savers/Ninja.saver/Contents/MacOS/Ninja
  Reason: image not found
2015-03-10 09:43:24.766 System Preferences[32495]: ScreenSaverModules: can't get principalClass for /Users/pupeno/Library/Screen Savers/Ninja.saver
```

The library in question is definitely there:

```
$ ls -w1 Library/Screen\ Savers/Ninja.saver/Contents/Frameworks/
libswiftAppKit.dylib
libswiftCore.dylib
libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
libswiftDarwin.dylib
libswiftDispatch.dylib
libswiftFoundation.dylib
libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
libswiftSecurity.dylib
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 9):

The problem was that the Runpath Search Path, for some reason, in this new target, was blank. I fixed this problem by adding this:

```
@executable_path/../Frameworks @loader_path/../Frameworks
```

to it (which I took from the working screensaver configuration). This is how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Like Pablo said, you need the following as your *Runtime Search Path*:

```
@executable_path/../Frameworks @loader_path/../Frameworks
```

This should be the default. Make sure it's there though. **You also need to set *Embedded Content Contains Swift Code* to YES** if you're using Swift. That took me awhile to figure out.

(Xcode should totally infer this. Oh well. I filed a radar for this awhile.)